# $_GET randomly gets unset in if statement

Tags: php, ajax

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this stupid problem but I have searched high and low and can not figure out why this wont work.

```
$tutorid = $_GET['userid'];

var_dump($tutorid);

//populate user tutoring subjects
if( isset($_POST['a'])) {
  $currentsubjects = get_current_user_subjects( $tutorid );
  unset($_POST['a']);
  echo json_encode($currentsubjects); return;
}
```

I have a simple `AJAX` function that sets `$_POST['a']` equal to something. The `var_dump($tutorid)` properly displays the id from the url. However the `$tutorid` in the `get_current_user_subjects` is sending `NULL`.

If I try a `var_dump` like this to check `$tutorid`

```
$tutorid = $_GET['userid'];

//populate user tutoring subjects
if( isset($_POST['a'])) {
  echo json_encode($tutorid); return;
  // $currentsubjects = get_current_user_subjects( $tutorid );
  // unset($_POST['a']);
  // echo json_encode($currentsubjects); return;
}
```

Then I get `NULL`. If I hard code in a tutorid in the `get_current_user_subjects( $tutorid )` (like add in 15 or something) the function returns data to console.log like expected but using the variable `$tutorid` stops it completely. I can't figure out why this is happening! Someone please enlighten me.

Here is the AJAX just incase. It works find on other pages so I am assuming the issue is with `$_GET`

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'profile.php',
  method: 'post',
  data: "a=true",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (x) {
    console.log(x);
  },
  error: function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
  }
```

Comment: are you really need `return;` . and please post your ajax here

Comment: Can you add the entire code in pastebin.com.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this method. So you can `POST` the `userid`

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'profile.php',
  method: 'post',
  data: {a: a, userid:userid},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (x) {
    console.log(x);
  },
  error: function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
  }
```

So in your form before the action. you can set `userid` in hidden form

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $userid;?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the userId to the session and take it from there. Or pass the userId with the ajax request. I dont think the logic is right in your code, as bsed on the info you have provided. Trying to take the id from $_GET in the requested page while your ajax method is post and no userId is passed with the request, is not right. From my knowledge, you wont have data in the $_GET array if the request to that page is not 'get'. Session provides InterPageCommunication. use session.